# Adding SSH keys to ssh-agent on demand

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

Instead of invoking `ssh-add` to add every key to `ssh-agent`, is it possible to add those keys automatically as soon as they are asked by ssh? Likewise agents launched by desktop environments do?

**EDIT:** What is the difference of agents launched by desktop environments (eg. forked from `gnome-keyring-daemon`) from agents launched by command line that would "add" this behaviour?

In Mate sessions (Linux Mint) as soon as ssh adds its first key to the agent a new process shows up, the one which SSH_AUTH_SOCK seems to point to, however there is a point preceding "ssh" name (".ssh" instead of "ssh"). This process is launched by "gnome-keyring-daemon", check the process PIDs on the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: @PhilipCouling Isn't it enough referring the keyring `gnome-keyring-daemon`?

Comment: The OP added `gnome-keyring-daemon` in response to my comment.

Answer (score 5):

Sufficiently recent versions of `ssh` (7.2, released early 2016, and newer) have an option AddKeysToAgent which does just that:

> AddKeysToAgent
>
> Specifies whether keys should be automatically added to a running ssh-agent(1).  If this option is set to yes and a key is
> loaded from a file, the key and its passphrase are added to the agent with the default lifetime, as if by ssh-add(1).  If
> this option is set to ask, ssh(1) will require confirmation using the SSH_ASKPASS program before adding a key (see
> ssh-add(1) for details).  If this option is set to confirm, each use of the key must be confirmed, as if the -c option
> was
> specified to ssh-add(1).  If this option is set to no, no keys are added to the agent.  The argument must be yes, confirm,
> ask, or no (the default).

As to differences in behaviour: the `ssh-agent` protocol follows [a standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-agent-02), which boils down to the following: the client (`ssh`, or `ssh-add`, or anybody else interested) knows who to talk to by looking at the environment variable `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`. The protocol, slightly simplified, has the following operations:

1. key management operations: add, remove, list available keys
2. message operations: sign, encrypt, etc.

Usually, you'd use `ssh-add` for the first kind. But, as said, new `ssh`s will add as well. When you ask about on-demand loading of keys: an agent might do something fancy when you ask for a list of available keys – the standard implementation requires you to add all the keys beforehand, but a desktop environment implementation might have keys in some wallet storage protected by a master password, and ask for the password when you first try to use any key. (Or maybe you mean keys are shared between different terminal windows? That's just a matter of getting the environment variable `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` into all your terminals, which is why it's good to start the agent in your session, so all terminals inherit the variable.)

Comment: That worked like a charm, thanks! But, there's still a question how do those "keyring-daemon" work changing `ssh-agent` behaviour?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. The daemons replace openssh's `ssh-agent` by their own, which also understands `ssh-add`.

Comment: I've improved the question "EDIT" session. Hopefully, it really improves the question.